# ESLint - eqeqeq not being disabled

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

In my React project I'm getting a billion different eqeqeq warnings when I compile/npm start. I'm trying to supress these warnings and Ive looked up/tried the following -

In package.json

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "eqeqeq": "off"
    }
  },
```

I also tried adding a `.eslintrc` file at the same level as `/src/` and `package.json` with the following config

```
{
    "rules": {
        "eqeqeq": "off"
      },
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module"
    }
  }
```

The parserOption is being read properly, because without it, alot of the files are warning that "import" keyword is reserved by ESLint, meaning this file should be being read properly however the eqeqeq warnings still persist.

I don't really understand why its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `root: true` to your config

Comment: Tried adding this to both the package.json and the .eslintrc, neither worked

Comment: The solution was quite obvious. However, no explanation given. Please improve your answer.